# Xcode- library not found for -lc++

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting this error when I archive my project

```
ld: library not found for -lc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The project work in simulator and iPhone device but when I archive project, I'm getting this error. can anyone help me?
Thanx in adv.

Comment: Have you tried the more general solution here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for

Answer (score 0):

Should be just a matter of adding -lc++ to the linker flags in the project settings, I'd have thought.

Add it under "Other Linker Flags" under "Linking" section of the "Build Settings" tab on your project's settings.