# Cocoapods and Xcode, ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode6.4

I have this pod file contains all of these libs

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

target "PP for iPad" do
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.1'
pod 'RaptureXML', '1.0'
pod 'NoticeView'
pod 'iVersion'
pod 'iRate'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.13.1'
pod 'StackMob'
pod 'SSZipArchive'
pod 'ODRefreshControl'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'LXPagingViews'
pod 'AQGridView'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
end
```

I ran it successfully with 'pod install' ... but when I try to run my project i get this error

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34287181/665961

Comment: I ran on a similar issue and I could solve it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37839050/3708095

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need set the property Build Active Architecture Only to NO in Target->Build Settings for Debug (in the Pods Project and/or in the target AFNetworking of Pods project). Also make sure that the corresponding Valid Architectures are included (e.g. 'armv7 arm64'). You may have received a Compilation Warning while building the project.

Comment: Yes, it does work. You have to toggle the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH setting in Target (not in Project) to YES and back to NO in order to reset some internal Xcode's cache reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try to makes your ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH setting in Target (not in Project) to YES and back to NO in order to reset some internal Xcode's cache reference.(NOTICE: Must make it YES first and then set it back to NO).