# library not found for -lCloudinary

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, cocoapods, ios-9-beta3

**Library not found** whenever I added from `pod`.

I have already added pod from terminal.

Error:

> ld:library not found for -lCloudinary
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to se invocation)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you perform `pod install` or `pod update` you **must use** the **new** `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` file instead of the old `<YourProject>.xcodeproj` file.

It happens because `.xcworkspace` contains your `.xcodeproj` and the `pods`. If you just run `.xcodeproj` the `pods` will be missing.