# library not found for -lHKDisplayModel clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

ld: library not found for -lHKDisplayModel
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "library not found for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of some missing `libraries` in your project.

Check in your **Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries**. Any of your `framework` may had been removed from there.

If you have imported any files into project then check `.m` (main) file for same does exists in `Targets` **(Project Name) -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources**.

If file does not exists then include it using (+) Add button shown. Also, if duplicate files exists (if any) then delete it.

Also check in **Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources**, if any file is displayed in a red color, then remove it and add it again.

Now press **cmd+shift+k** to clean the project. New Build should not display this error.

Comment: i don't know still thatsy i posted this. ;-)