# xcodebuild command to create archive for App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, archive, xcodebuild

I am trying to archive my project for one of my project schemes using: `xcodebuild` command,

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProj.xcworkspace  -scheme AppScheme -sdk iphoneos 
-configuration AppStoreDistribution TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY='1' 
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Distribution: myDistName (ABCDEFGHIJ-112233)' 
PROVISIONING_PROFILE='A11111-22222-33333S-*!123-12332123123123' 
PRODUCT_NAME='TESTAPP' PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER='com.myapp.appapp.test' 
-arch armv7 archive
```

hear above command works and build the app but at the end gives error like below

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I archive it manually it will archive successfully,I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik,. it give same error

Comment: in your project is support to arm64

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes it does support armv6,arm64,armv7

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to install [fastlane](https://fabric.io/features/distribution?utm_campaign=fastlane.tools) in to your project. Very easy to install and you can export archive with the tiniest command "gym".

Comment: ok then it's hard to tell the exact problem but you can try these things

Comment: 1. removing the contents of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: i tried all, and reinstalling cocoapods, and resetting every path and all, still it gives same error

Comment: This comment is more of an advertisement for fastlane, than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: I just shared my personal experience.