# Ionic2 Xcode Build Failure Cocoapods?

Tags: xcode, ionic2, cocoapods

Hi I am building an app using ionic2 and recently installed the push plugin (I'm normally a windows user) I wanted to install this on iOS so on my Mac mini I installed push plugin then was required to install cocoa pods which I did.

Now when I try to install my app in Xcode on an actual iPhone device I get the error in Xcode:

ld: library not found for -lPods-MyApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Showing Recent Errors Only
ld: library not found for -lPods-MyApp

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea how to debug this and am at a complete loss. I have tried ionic platform rm iOS then add iOS but I still get the same error.

Anyone else had this issue or can point in the right direction? A day spent on this so far and still banging my head against the wall!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makesure you are opening the .xcworkspace file not the .xcproject after the PODS installation is completed. You may also refer to this answer: [Error "library not found for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for)