# ld: library not found for -lVuforia

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm integrating unity project to native ios project in c++. But I'm getting error

```
ld: library not found for -lVuforia
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

while building xcode project.

I'm using

- xCode : 8.2.1
- Unity : 5.6.1f1

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Framework]

Comment: FYI : I followed this [https://the-nerd.be/2015/11/13/integrate-unity-5-in-a-native-ios-app-with-xcode-7/](https://the-nerd.be/2015/11/13/integrate-unity-5-in-a-native-ios-app-with-xcode-7/) for integration

Comment: Please try to remove framework/library and then add it again. Make sure when you are adding "copy items if needed" is checked.. And there might be an issue of hierarchy of libraries in project. Keep all at same place and same level of folders.

Comment: Structure is fine.. Now check build settings.. library search path.. $(SRCROOT)/Libraries

Comment: I have added this "$(SRCROOT)/../../LoadScene_unity_build/Libraries" in Library Search Paths. I also tried with removing "", but no luck... :(

Comment: Have you tried with deleting derived data?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for). That might be helpful.

Comment: I tried all answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for), but didn't work... :(

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you have the "Vuforia" library included in your build.
Under your Unity project, look for a file called Vuforia.framework. This file's inspector should have "iOS" marked in it, so it gets included in the generated Xcode project.

Comment: Hm, I can't find any file named "Vuforia.framework" under unity project, so how can I get this file??

Comment: do you know if Vuforia are using CocoaPods ?

Comment: Sorry man, I'm kinda noob in ios stuffs... Will you explain me in details, what I will need to fix this....

Comment: are you using Vuforia in your game / app ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using vuforia 6

Answer (score 1):

If you integrated a Unity scene using Vuforia, you should be able to see those libraries `libVuforia.a` and `libVuforiaUnityPlayer.a` at the path *Demo/Vendor/Unity/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/*

If you don't see those libraries you should try to integrate your Unity scene once again. If they're here, in Xcode go to *Build Phases*, then *Link Binary With Libraries* and make sure you have those above libraries as well as `libiPhone.a` (those are the libraries given by your Unity scene and you definitely need them), if not add them.

Also, I believe you followed a tutorial to integrate a normal Unity scene, however when you use Vuforia you need to make some other steps. For instance, you'll have to add the folder references of *Data* AND *QCAR*. I recommend you to try once again your integration with this [tutorial](https://github.com/keyv/iOSUnityVuforiaGuide) which is more relevant to what you want to do.

I hope this will be useful to you and I wish you good luck in your integration.

Comment: Everything (libraries you mentioned) is there in project... I will try [https://github.com/keyv/iOSUnityVuforiaGuide](https://github.com/keyv/iOSUnityVuforiaGuide) and let you know if facing the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Because your code cannot find libVuforia.a, which is library. You have to set "Library search path" at "Build Setting"

or use vuforia sdk
1. download vuforia sdk https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk 
2. create or put your source code put in Sample folder in vuforia-sdk-ios-7-0-43

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU0kc.png)

3.In your project Go to Target > Build Setting > Search Paths > Library Search Path. and Click +

../../build/lib/arm

4.In your project Go to Target > Build Setting > Search Paths > Header Search Path. and Click +

../../build/include

5.Run