# library not found for -lFPStaticServer

Tags: ios, react-native

I am having issue in building react native code... have any idea what it is?

```
ld: library not found for -lFPStaticServer
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: add more data to understand what happened

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "library not found for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for)