# react-native-fbads production build error on iOS - library not found

Tags: ios, react-native, native-module

### Description

I can't build a production build of my react-native app with react-native-fbads as a dependency.

I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lReactNativeAdsFacebook
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When building for production release with this library I encounter this problem on iOS. Android is working fine. I am using the newest version from npm but it also happens with the master branch.

When setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES` in XCode `Build Settings` and building for an iPhone 7 iOS 12 everything works fine. This is not a solution for production because older versions should also be supported.

With 4.2.0 it's building fine.

**stack trace**

```
Ld /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/playground.build/Release-iphonesimulator/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground normal x86_64 (in target: playground)
cd /Users/jobeso/projects/playground/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk -L/Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jobeso/projects/playground/ios/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork -filelist /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/playground.build/Release-iphonesimulator/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/playground.build/Release-iphonesimulator/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground_lto.o -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lc++ -lxml2 -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework FBAudienceNetwork -framework Foundation -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework WebKit -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/playground.build/Release-iphonesimulator/playground.build/playground.app-Simulated.xcent /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTBlob.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTAnimation.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libReact.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a -lPods-playground -lReactNativeAdsFacebook -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/playground.build/Release-iphonesimulator/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jobeso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/playground-breooeaonoutyzaiywigdxwsujyp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/playground.build/Release-iphonesimulator/playground.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/playground
```

### Reproducible Demo

[sample project on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Jobeso/playground/tree/fbads-example)

#### issue

[issue on github](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads/issues/144)

Comment: Did you try the methods stated in this Stackoverflow question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the header search paths in the library. A pr with a fix is in the linked github issue.