# Xcode compiles react-native app with Linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I deploy a react-native  app  to iPhone, encounter a linker error when compile with Xcode,

```
ld: library not found for -lRNLocationPermissions
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Xcode and React-Native configuration:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9
Xcode: 10.2.1
```

Please feel free to comment on how to fix this error.

Comment: Remove and reinstall node_modules. Also clear the DerivedData. rebuild again

Comment: similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for/29497314

Comment: I didn't find xcworkspace, I don't know it is required. Create a new Podfile, 1. "Pod Init"; because there are some duplication, then edit the Podfile to remove duplication. 2. "Pod Install"; create a new xcworkspace successfully. 3. open xcworkspace with Xcode; change it to release and connect iPhone with USB, a same linker error when compile with Xcode.