# iOS is unable to build due to react-native-svg

Tags: android, react-native

I have integrated react-native-svg for svg support,
for android its working like charm ,but in iOS its unable to build & throwing **library not found for -lRNSVG** error.

[image]

Linked GitHub issue - https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1469

Comment: you did `cd iOS && pod install`?

Comment: yes , pod install didn't work & also tried this related issue- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24050167/11383477