# xcode 8 - ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can someone tell me how to fix this error in xcode 8?

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/40876733/393697
Please see there.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o error while running app in device with xcode 8.0 with iOS10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632155/ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt1-3-1-o-error-while-running-app-in-device-with-xc)

Comment: How do I mark my question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Error: ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o

Solution: If your project source have deployment target from iOS 5.0 then change it to iOS 6.0 or later and your error will be fix. Now that work fine for device too.

Comment: Thanks, This helped.