# Lambdanative can compile for OSX but not iOS

Tags: ios, scheme, gambit, lambdanative

I'm running Sierra with XCode 8.3 including command line tools. I can use Gambit to compile to OSX native code. I can use lambdanative to compile the test Calculator app to OSX but when I try to configure and then compile for iOS I get the following error in verbose mode:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/querist/.lambdanative/tmp_install/gambc-v4_7_9':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: failed with exit code 77
```

There is no config.log to read. I've done a search for it and there is not one related to this project.

Any ideas? I really like the idea of being able to develop iOS apps in Scheme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this may be too late, but in case somebody else stumbles upon this, I though I'd try to explain.

`config.log` is placed in the library output directory, not your working folder. You can look for it by running `find ~/Library/ -name 'config.log'`.

In my case, `config.log` revealed the problem is that it can't find some version of a `crt` library. This problem is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632155/ld-library-not-found-for-lcrt1-3-1-o-error-while-running-app-in-device-with-xc).

I edited my `./SETUP` file from my lamdbanative working directory folder, so that `IOSVERSION` went from the `5.1.1` default to `6.0`. That solved the problem for me.