# ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-cli

I m not using cocopad, after building project its giving me "ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) " error

Build settings -    Bitcode -no
Build Active Architectures Only = no

tried Build Active Architectures Only to yes also but same error displaying

Please help me regarding this,

thank u

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471968/xcode-linker-error-library-not-found-for-ladmobdevice

Comment: Is your analytics sdk up to date?