# Xcode linker failing when building Unity3D iPhone project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

Unity is able to build the Xcode project but when I go to build the project to my iPhone it throws 50 warning(I heard this is fine with a Unity project) and it fails at the linker.

```
Ld /Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Dribble.app/Dribble normal arm64
    cd /Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk -L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb -L/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0 -L/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/Libraries -L/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase -F/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -F/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks -F/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/collinnapier/Documents/Unity/Dribble/Builds/0.1.0/UnityAds -filelist /Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dribble.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Dribble-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -miphoneos-version-min=11.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dribble_lto.o -fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lc++ -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -framework MediaToolbox -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lApp -lAuth -framework StoreKit -weak_framework Metal -framework UnityAds -weak_framework AdSupport -framework CoreTelephony -lPods-Unity-iPhone -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Dribble_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Dribble.app/Dribble

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/collinnapier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bradioenzitmtgewmwevmohjyqur/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: library not found for -lGTMSessionFetcher
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe the reference for the library is messed up. Try removing the reference and adding it again. See these similar questions for more info on how to do that and other suggestions.

[Error "library not found for"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050012/error-library-not-found-for)

[XCode linker error : library not found for -lAdMobDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471968/xcode-linker-error-library-not-found-for-ladmobdevice)

Answer (score 0):

Update minimum iOS version to a newer version in "Unity --> Edit --> Project Settings --> Player --> iOS Settings --> Other Settings --> Target minimum iOS Version" (12.0 in my case) and fix Unity version "Unity Dashboard --> Cloud Build --> Config --> in iOS profile --> Basic Info Unity version" (2021.2.0b13 in my case).
This fix my issue.